# Query regarding Current Account in a conventional bank

Tags: practical-islam, riba, banking

Well I know that current account itself is not haram, because there is no interest involved in it.
And i know that it is better to use Islamic banks.
But my question is that if my company only pays me through a bank which is interest based (conventional) bank, then what will be the ruling applicable on me for opening a current account in it?
I mean is it permissible or not?

Comment: If your bank account accumulates interest monthly for example, then you should get rid of that interest by either giving it back to the bank or donating it to charity, the poor. I recommend the latter option.

Comment: Current accounts typically do **not** pay interest. Rather you will likely  be paying them a fee for the banking privileges. Having such an account is permissible if necessary as it is in your situation. See https://islamqa.info/en/answers/226729/ and https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/84356/ However you should first ask your employer, as some employers will allow you to receive payments in bank of your own choice, or they might allow you to receive a check, in which case it is better to use an Islamic bank.